# How to add contacts custom app account like below screen shot

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, cncontact

[image]
I'm developing an app which needs its own contacts to be visible in their contacts. Like Whatsapp, I need to show the contact nos that they are registered in my app.

For example, If you add a Friend's whatsapp no in contacts, it will show **Found in Whatsapp**. So I'm also need the same kind of functionality for my app.

When i install my app, my app should be added to the above list. (Have a look at above screenshot).

I've searched and found nothing about this. So any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i found the solution , if u add callkit and need to config , then it will added on the list , https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/Speakerbox/SpeakerboxUsingCallKittocreateaVoIPapp.zip , download the source and run the project , after installation complete open contacts and add social profile, then you will find 'Speakerbox' on the social profile.

Answer (score 2):

Just add the below snippet into your info.Plist to get your app name in list

`<key>NSUserActivityTypes</key>
    <array>
        <string>INStartAudioCallIntent</string>
    </array>`

[Check this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSkHJ.png)